# Jhipster changing generator options

Tags: jhipster

I'm new to jhipster, I was wondering that if once I run the "yo jhipster" is there a way to go back and change some of the option selected? Example to enable Compass/SASS.

If I try to install a new generator (by calling "yo" alone), i'm not sure what to install. Compass-extension or Sass ? Or both or something else as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

You can change the file `.yo-rc.json` ("useCompass": true, etc) and then run `yo jhipster` in the root directory. Depends of the change in `.yo.rc.json` must to rerun entity generators with `yo jhipster:entity <name>`.

Comment: Is there a way of "merging in" the changes (like an upgrade; through git) instead of being prompted to overwrite files entirely?

Answer (score 7):

Found the answer on the JHipster site actually...maybe it just got added or simply that I can't read :)

https://jhipster.github.io/creating_an_entity.html (see section Generating an entity a second time)